# Is it possible to serve different versions of a static page with nextjs on vercel according to useragent (device type)?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

The nextjs page `/users/[userid]` is statically rendered on build time in the vercel platform.
Is there anyway to serve two different versions of that page through some configuration on vercel or nextjs according to the user-agent (device-type) ? (while keeping it static)

A mobile user requesting `example.com/users/userid` getting a different static page than the desktop user requesting the same path.

Comment: the context object can give you access to the user-agent header: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps#context-object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment, this is not available. However, we are working on an update that should make it possible.

Stay tuned for updates on both the Vercel platform and Next.js.

EDIT: This is now possible with the use of the "has" property and "rewrites":

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return {
      beforeFiles: [
        {
          source: '/some-page',
          destination: '/somewhere-else',
          has: [{
            type: 'header', 
            key: 'user-header',
            value: 'insert-regex-here'
          }],
        },
      ],
      // ...
    }
  },
}
```

EDIT2: This is now even easier with the use of [Edge Middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware)

Comment: sweet! thanks for the info. Would you by any chance be able to disclose a very rough estimated timeline for this feature ?   Just trying to gauge wether it's worth building an interim solution or not...

Comment: I cannot. But you should give the team at least 7d

Comment: Updated the original comment to include Edge Middleware. It is a great option for this case!

Comment: Why `user-header` and not `User-Agent`? Anyway it does not work. Would you check? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71968407/how-to-url-rewrite-based-on-host-in-next-js

Comment: Certainly. I believe the answer would also be better by using Edge Functions. Will do that soon.