# Why og:image / og:url can not be followed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

Got this error in Facebook Graph API Explorer, for scrape:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid parameter",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 1611071,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "URL Follow Failed",
    "error_user_msg": "There was an error in fetching the object at URL 'https://tikex-dev.com/kubl/fl50/j1vd/r36s', or one of the URLs specified via a redirect or the 'og:url' property including one of https://t44-post-cover.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/fr1n.",
    "fbtrace_id": "AMZdGCazFLYGP6MfT-YZ-WF"
  }
}
```

service used: `?scrape=true&id=https://tikex-dev.com/kubl/fl50/j1vd/r36s`

Sharing page point to a gif file with `og:image` and `og:url`. what is wrong? If I share the gif file in Facebook, not sharing page, gif is loaded, rendered, animated.

Does AWS need to provide something more in header?

What `OAuthException` means?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag with `og:url` is supposed to be readable and providing OG tags. Your gif is not readable, it's got a binary mime-type.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/getting-started/versioned-link/?locale=en_US

> The path specified for og:url does not need to be a page that renders in the browser. However, it must respond to the Facebook crawler and return og:* meta tags.

And

> When the path referred to by og:url returns an og:url link that is different, the new link is followed. The sharing details that Facebook uses are the ones at the final link in the redirect chain. The final link in the chain should also include the og:url meta tag. If og:url isn't specified, then the URL of the page is assumed to be the canonical URL.

The canonical tag is more important than the `og:url` tag equivalent tho, use it too:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://tikex-dev.com/kubl/fl50/j1vd/r36s">
```

In your setup, you have a webpage with `text/html` that redirects to a gif with type `image/gif`.

The gif has no CORS headers at https://t44-post-cover.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/i61t

Comment: Thanks, the lesson for me, Facebook crawler should be served differently than normal visitors. Still I face with an obstackle, maybe you can help here also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71968407/how-to-rewrite-based-on-host-in-next-js