# Why og:url can not point to og:image?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, share-open-graph, facebook-debugger

I have this sharing page: https://tikex-dev.com/kubl/34lw/j1vd/ceay

Though `og:url` is the same as `og:image`, og:url value in Facebook Debugger will not show the meta tag value, but the url of the sharing page. Why?

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://t44-post-cover.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/pbs8">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://t44-post-cover.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/pbs8">
```

[image]

Anyway og:image points to a GIF file.

And there is an other problem also, I can not see the preview of the image in Facebook Debugger, and when sharing page is shared on Facebook, GIF is a static image, not animating. Why?

Comment: I don't  know if  itsolves the issue but you  should  add a `<meta>` canonical tag. The FB  tool might just assume the  URL typed is  the real `og:url`.

Comment: Yes, but `og:url` is added. If you check in question.

Comment: Trying to scrape the image URL itself gets a 403, and when I try to visit it in my browser, I get an XML response containing "AccessDenied"

Comment: Yes, you are right, url changed a bit, I applied one fix, but still there is an issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72933000/how-aws-prevent-facebook-image-sharing-url-follow-failed

Answer (score 1):

##### Short answer:

> The path specified for og:url does not need to be a page that renders in the browser. However, it **must respond to the Facebook crawler and return og:... meta tags**. For details on detecting the Facebook crawler, see The Facebook Crawler.

##### More details:

The `og:url` is an equivalent to a `meta` `canonical` tag - use it, canonical is the most important canonization tag.

> When the path referred to by og:url returns an og:url link that is different, the new link is followed. The sharing details that Facebook uses are the ones at the final link in the redirect chain. The final link in the chain should also include the og:url meta tag. If og:url isn't specified, then the URL of the page is assumed to be the canonical URL.

###### Some limitations apply because you are using different domains:

> Starting February 3, 2020, you will no longer be able to specify URLs
> with a different domain as the canonical URL, unless that domain has
> explicitly added your domain to an allow list using the Webmaster
> tool.

The domain `t44-post-cover.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` does not match `tikex-dev.com`.

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/getting-started/versioned-link/?locale=en_US