# Where inputURL and og:url Meta Tag comes in Facebook Sharing Debugger?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-debugger

Checking this url: https://giphy.com/gifs/xbox-xbox-series-x-s-my-hero-ultra-rumble-RtS1FrFvjQ8zRoA14O

Where highlighted fields coming? Which meta field are those?

I have the same meta tag structure in my page as in Giphy page, but those fields are not there.

https://tikex-dev.com/kubl/fl50/j1vd/r36s

[image]

---

I made an experiment, I put the head from Giphy page to my testing website sub page, and those highlighted infos are not visible anymore in the Facebook Debugger when I analyse it: https://tikex-dev.com/test

Why? Where they gone?

[image]

Comment: The "input URL" is what URL you gave the tool to debug to begin with, and `og:meta` comes from the meta tag ...

Comment: Hi, would you elaborate a bit? I searched the html, and there is no keywork like `og:meta`. What does it mean "gave the tool to debug to begin with" :D

Comment: I meant `og:url`, exactly as it says there. _"What does it mean 'gave the tool to debug to begin with'"_ - the URL you typed into the input field, to tell the tool which URL you wanted it to debug ...

Comment: I understand now, but why "Redirect Path" section is missing, when I run Debugger with my own page, there is no "Redirect Path" section.

Comment: Maybe Giphy checks wether request comes from Facebook scraper, and then they redirect to the file? Anyway they show the sharing page?

Comment: I don't know, could have to do with the explicitly specified `canonical`. (Although giphy appears to set that as well, also to a different value than `og:url`. But I can only check what they serve to my browser here, might be that the serve something different to the Facebook scraper.)

Comment: We will see wether it works or not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71968407/how-redirect-next-js-based-on-source-of-a-request